# Print/Warning for Null values with column name and count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame which has couple of columns which has null values. currently I am doing the following:

```
import warnings
if df.columns[df.isnull().any()].any(): 
     warnings.warn("Found Null Value on column: " + str(df[df.columns[df.isnull().any()]].isnull().sum()))
```

which prints out the following

```
UserWarning: Found Null Value on column: qty    50
dtype: int64
```

I want something like

```
UserWarning: Found Null Value on column: qty    count: 50
```

Comment: adding iloc[0] at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using f-strings, available in Python 3.6+. Also possible using `str.format`. Instead of checking `pd.Series.any`, we can simply test whether `nulls_sum` is non-zero.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, np.nan, 1], [np.nan, 2, 3]])

import warnings

for col in df.columns:
    nulls_sum = df[col].isnull().sum()
    if nulls_sum:
        warnings.warn(f"Found Null Value on column: {col}, count: {nulls_sum}")

UserWarning: Found Null Value on column: 0, count: 1
UserWarning: Found Null Value on column: 1, count: 1
```